Escape colon in Vue router wikipedia-style
Context
I've been trying to replicate what wikipedia does with their URL
It works something like
/[Namespace]:[PageName]
/[PageName]
So if I go to /randompage I get as params:

namespace: ''
page name: 'randompage'

and if I go to /whatever:anotherpage I get:

namespace: 'whatever'
page name: 'anotherpage'

Problem
My issue lies in not being able to escape the colon :.
For example, if I use - instead the route string is as simple as :namespace-:pagename. I tried doing :namespace::pagename and got very weird results. As an example, when I tried to match /hi:bye I got as namespace h and as page name i:bye
(see this).
Similar results with everything else I tried (:template\\::pagename, :template()\\::pagename).
What's the proper way of handling this issue in Vue Router?

A workaround would be to use the namespace aka i: from the i:bye with a regex, filter or alike. Sounds feasible.

You can specify the regular expression ([^:]+) which will capture all characters up to the colon paths.esm.dev:
/:namespace([^:]+):pagename

In this case pagename will be :bye. If the colon in this parameter will bother you, then you can get rid of it, for example, when the route is defined, like this:
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
   {
    path: '/:namespace([^:]+):pagename(.+)',
    name: 'routeName',
    component: TheComponent,
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      if (to.params.pagename) {
        to.params.pagename = String(to.params.pagename).replace(/^:/, '');
      };
      next();
    }
   },
  ],
});


You can also collect any options separated by colons without specifying them in path:
{
  path: '/:page',
  name: 'routeName',
  component: TheComponent,
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    if (to.params.page) {
      const params = String(to.params.page).split(':');
      to.params = { params };
    }
    next();
  }
}

In this case, in route /hi:bye:anything, you will get { "params": [ "hi", "bye", "anything" ] }

Very good resource you got here sir!

Thank! But is not perfect. I will update the answer to remove the : from pagename

Cool!, the : is annoying but a super big improvement! Kinda odd to not be able to find this in the documentation :( Thank you very much

Also, I used this question to prove a point to my classmates: ChatGPT sucks; StackOverflow rocks. ChatGPT wanted me to do the routing inside the component which I believe is kinda dirty... right?

why doesn't something like /:namespace([^:]+)\\::pagename work? guess i'll go for the second approach
